# Python Matplotlib How to Make Background Between and Around Subplots White?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I can't seem to get an image made by a plot in jupyter notebook to have a white background everywhere. Currently I have only been able to get the subplots to have a white background but this frustratingly makes the text in the plot such as the title practically invisible when viewing the image in some programs due to how some programs treat transparent as black. I have also tried to use savefig() with settings with no better results.

I have also tried `fig.set_facecolor('white')` with no change.

Does anyone know how to define a background color for the area not directly in the subplots?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib notebook
plt.style.use('seaborn-paper')
```

...

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols = 3, figsize = (30, 10))
fig.set_facecolor('white')
LL.Serises_Win_Ratio.plot(ax = axes[0, 0], legend = True);
axes[0, 0].set_ylabel('Rivalry Game Win Ratio')
axes[0, 0].set_title('Lakers Rivalry Game Win Ratio Vs Season Avg Attendance')

LL.Avg.plot(secondary_y = True, style='r', ax = axes[0, 0], legend = True)
LC.Serises_Win_Ratio.plot(ax = axes[1, 0], legend = True);
axes[1, 0].set_ylabel('Rivalry Game Win Ratio')
axes[1, 0].set_title('Clippers Rivalry Game Ratio Vs Season Avg Attendance')
LC.Avg.plot(secondary_y = True, style = 'r', ax = axes[1, 0], legend = True)

LL_att.ORtg.plot(ax = axes[0, 2], legend = True); 
axes[0, 2].set_ylabel('Season Avg Score')
axes[0, 2].set_title('Lakers Season Avg Score Vs Season Avg Attendance')
LL_att.Avg.plot(secondary_y = True, style = 'r', ax=axes[0, 2], legend = True)
LC_att.ORtg.plot(ax = axes[1, 2], legend = True); 
axes[1, 2].set_ylabel('Season Avg Score')
axes[1, 2].set_title('Clippers Season Avg Score Vs Season Avg Attendance')
LC_att.Avg.plot(secondary_y = True, style = 'r', ax = axes[1, 2], legend = True)

LL_win.Win_ratio.plot(ax = axes[0, 1], legend = True); 
axes[0, 1].set_ylabel('Season Win Ratio')
axes[0, 1].set_title('Lakers Season Win Ratio Vs Season Avg Attendance')
LL_win.Avg.plot(secondary_y = True, style = 'r', ax = axes[0, 1], legend = True)
LC_win.Win_ratio.plot(ax = axes[1, 1], legend = True); 
axes[1, 1].set_ylabel('Season Win Ratio')
axes[1, 1].set_title('Clippers Season Win Ratio Vs Season Avg Attendance')
LC_win.Avg.plot(secondary_y = True, style = 'r', ax = axes[1, 1], legend = True)
plt.suptitle('LA, CA USA Lakers/Clippers Average Attendance Compared to Rivalry Game Win Ratio, Season Win Ratio and Average Score By Season 93-94 to 13-14')
plt.savefig('C:\\Assn4.png', transparent = False, facecolor = 'w', edgecolor='w', frameon = False)
```

Current Image Output:

[image]

Which looks great until you view just the image in a browser like Google Chrome that treats transparent as black and then its just 6 graphs with no titles or axes labels like:

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. However since there might be a bug involved, I'm not currently sure what the expected behaviour for those arguments is. Did you try `frameon = True`? Since you essentially *do want*  a frame.

Comment: frameon = True in savefig() had no visual difference that I could see. I ended up opening the image an editor and saving the file with transparency disabled. Filling the transparent area with white wasn't an optimal solution because the space inside text was transparent which made the text look bad.

Comment: Interesting. What version of matplotlib are you using?

Comment: Apparently I had been using matplotlib 2.1.2 instead of the current 2.2.2 release. After figuring out how to get Anaconda Navigator to update libraries I am now getting the desired white background in the file created by savefig(). Thank you so much!